# Why is に used in this sentence? 彼は彼女に見覚えがある。

Tags: particles, particle-に, particle-が

Why is に used in this sentence?

> 彼は彼女に見覚えがある。

Also, why is 見覚え marked by が?

Answer (score 3):

「彼女」はこの文における目的語です。

「見覚えがある」というのをひとかたまりの述語（＝verb）として捉えたとき、この述語の目的語に当たるのが「彼女」です。

日本語では名詞が目的語であることを示すのに助詞を必要とします。この場合は「に」です。

例

彼は彼女に怒りをおぼえた。＝彼は彼女に怒った

また「見覚えがある」の「が」もまた助詞です。
「見覚え」は名詞で、主語となるので、「ある」に対する主語であることを示すため「が」という助詞がついています。

Answer (score 2):

見覚え is a noun here, hence it's marked with が as the subject of ある.

見覚えがある is a set phrase meaning "to recognize" by sight.  The particle に here marks that *in* which one finds *familiarity*.  Thus,

> 彼は彼女に見覚えがある

means "He recognizes her".